# Dynamically changing name of ng-show and scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I have retrieving the contents from database using $http.get api and displaying each record using `ng-repeat`. For each record i have a `like and comment` button. On clicking on `comment button`, i will show `input box with send button` previously it will be hidden(using ng-show). The problem is- on clicking any one of the record comment button,all other records input box with send button will be shown including clicked.

```
<div ng-repeat="dat in details">
  <ul>
    <li><b>Product:</b><span> {{dat.product_name}}</span></li>
  </ul>
  <button style="background-color:#4C97C8;color:white;height:30px" class="btn buttonlike" ng-click="likebtn(dat.id,loginname)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span><strong> Like</strong></button>   
  <button style="background-color:#4C97C8;color:white;height:30px" class="btn" ng-click="mycomment()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span><strong> Comment</strong></button>
  <div class="input-group" ng-show="comment1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="comment" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`mycomment()` method in script looks like-

```
$scope.comment1= false;
$scope.mycomment = function() {
    $scope.comment1= true;
}
```

How can i change the name of ng-show-"comment1" dynamically(if I change, I have to change the name in script too) ?? is there any other way?

Comment: in ng-repeat, you can use ng-init, so you can initialize some vars that only affects to the view(html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="dat in details | filter : { product_name : textname} as results">
  <hr/>
  <p style="color:#4C97C8;" class="lead"><strong>{{dat.summary}}</strong></p>
  <ul>
    <li><b>Product:</b><span> {{dat.product_name}}</span></li>
    <li><b>Product Manager:</b><span> {{dat.first_name}} {{dat.last_name}}</span></li>
    <li><b>Description:</b><span> {{dat.description}}</span></li>
  </ul>
  <button style="background-color:#4C97C8;color:white;height:30px" class="btn buttonlike" ng-click="likebtn(dat.id,loginname)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span><strong> Like</strong></button>   
  <button style="background-color:#4C97C8;color:white;height:30px" class="btn" ng-click="comment=true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span><strong> Comment</strong></button>
  <div class="input-group" ng-show="comment">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="comment" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of `ng-click="mycomment()"` and `ng-show="comment1"`: `ng-click="comment=true"` and `ng-show="comment"` accordingly. `$scope.comment1` and `$scope.mycomment` are not needed.

Comment: For input tag (4th line from last ), if i append ng-model="somename" And in controller i referred it as $scope.somename. The problem is whatever i enter it in input , it wont update in controller. i used it in alert(), it throws undefined.  Why??

Comment: Each `ng-repeat` has it's own scope, which is located inside main `$scope`, which you used inside your controller. So, instead of `ng-model='somename'` you should write `ng-model='$parent.somename'`, to reach desired result

Comment: can u provide solution for this same kind of question on this link?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300628/dynamically-changing-the-name-on-button-after-click