# Dynamically changing the name on button after click

Tags: angularjs

I have retrieving the contents from database using $http.get api and displaying each record using `ng-repeat`. For each record i have a `like and comment button.` On clicking on like button, i m inserting a record using $http.post and i have to `change the name of button to "Liked"`.The problem is- on clicking any one of the record like button, all other records like button name changes to Liked including clicked button.

```
 <div ng-repeat="dat in details | filter : { product_name : textname} as results">          
        <p style="color:#4C97C8;" class="lead"><strong>{{dat.summary}}</strong></p>
        <ul>
          <li><b>Product:</b><span> {{dat.product_name}}</span></li>
          <li><b>Product Manager:</b><span> {{dat.first_name}} {{dat.last_name}}</span></li>
          <li><b>Description:</b><span> {{dat.description}}</span></li>
        </ul>
        <button style="background-color:#4C97C8;color:white;height:30px" class="btn buttonlike" ng-click="likebtn(dat.id,loginname)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span><strong> {{ likebtnname }}</strong></button>   
        <button style="background-color:#4C97C8;color:white;height:30px" class="btn" ng-disabled="comment" ng-click="comment=true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span><strong> Comment</strong></button>
        <div class="input-group " ng-show="comment">
            <input type="text" id="commentarea" name="commentarea" class="form-control" placeholder="comment" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" ng-model="takecomment">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2" ng-click="takecomment=mycomment(dat.id,takecomment)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

likebtn() method inside script/controller is

```
$scope.likebtnname="Like";
$scope.likebtn = function(idvalue,namevalue) {

  var likereque = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: "https://url/Likes",
    headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: {
      "platform": {
       "record": { "idea_record": idvalue,
                   "liker": $scope.loginname
                 }
                 }
          }
  }
  $http(likereque).then(function(){
       alert("Liked Successfully");
       $scope.likebtnname="Liked"; },
     function(){alert("try again");});
  }
```

How can i change the name of clicked button only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<button style="background-color:#4C97C8;color:white;height:30px" class="btn buttonlike" ng-click="$parent.likebtn(dat.id,loginname, dat)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span><strong> {{ dat.likebtnname||'Like' }}</strong></button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.likebtn = function(idvalue,namevalue,dat) {

  var likereque = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: "https://url/Likes",
    headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: {
      "platform": {
       "record": { "idea_record": idvalue,
                   "liker": $scope.loginname
                 }
                 }
          }
  }
  $http(likereque).then(function(){
       alert("Liked Successfully");
       dat.likebtnname="Liked"; },
     function(){alert("try again");});
  }
```

Comment: why you have used dat reference here {{ dat.likebtnname||'Like' }}. There is no field name called likebtnname for object

Comment: I updated answer: added `$parent` to `$parent.likebtn(dat.id,loginname, dat)`

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have **one** variable `$scope.likebtnname`, so when you change it, it changes for all.
You can use `track by $index` for the ng-repeat, then use an array `$scope.likebtnname[$index]` and change only the one you need passing the `$index`.

Comment: can u explain more on how u can access $index inside controller. Do i need to pass it as an argument while calling a method to use it as $scope.likebtnname[$index]?

Comment: You can do `ng-click="likebtn(dat.id,loginname, $index)"` in the view. <br>Set your function as `$scope.likebtn = function(idvalue,namevalue,index)` <br>And  then inside the function `$scope.likebtnname[index]="Liked";`

Comment: can u explain how you will create array $scope.likebtnname[index] in this case?  bcz i was using this as an $scope.likebtnname ng-model

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I don't see any ngmodel `$scope.likebtnname`. If I understand correct, at ng-repeat you can do `ng-init="likebtnname[$index]='Like'"` and in ctrl `$scope.likebtnames = [];` to initialize the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since they all have same name to it is a common occurrence so one solution canbe dynamically changing the name.
First track by $index

```
div ng-repeat="dat in details track by $index| filter : { product_name : textname} as results">
```

Then in your button add an ID

```
 <button style="background-color:#4C97C8; ng-model="$index"
```

Then pass that id in your function

```
 ng-click="likebtn(dat.id,loginname,$index)"
```

then by using that id update dom

```
$scope[id]="Liked";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $http(likereque).then(function successCallback(){
      alert("Liked Successfully");
      dat.likebtnname="Liked"; 
   },
   errorCallback function(){
      alert("try again");
    });
 }
```